# phpmyadmin не добавляет в базу данные

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, linux-mint, lamp

перешёл с Windows на Linux Mint , на Windows на сервере выполнялись все php скрипты , развернул сервер на Linux и скрипт не добавляет данные в базу , предполагаю что я не правильно настроил phpmyadmin т.к. на windows данный скрипт выполнялся не однократно . в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: причем пхпадмин к пхп скриптам? пхпадмин это вьюшка для пользователей. Скрипты в студию

Comment: да не добавляются в сам phpmyadmin , он даже ошибку не выводит после нажатия на кнопку типо что к базе не подключился и на код не жалуется он просто не заносит данные

Comment: Если "не добавляются" должно быть сообщение об ошибке. Укажите его. Если success то  вы куда-то не туда админом подключаетесь, или неверно коннект прописали.

Comment: Ошибку в вопросе покажите.

Comment: Нету ошибки , вообще не чего не выводит! когда ошибка в коде браузер ругается и говорит что не подключён к базе или ошибка в коде, тут-же он просто перезагружает страницу и всё!

Comment: Ну мы не ванги, вы ни кода не добавили, ничего вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для версии php < 7 (желательно < 5.5)

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink) {
    echo 'Соединение установлено.';
} else {
    die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');
}

$database = 'dbbase';
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected) {
    echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
} else {
    die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');
}
?>
```

Для версии php >= 7 (желательно >= 5.5)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Что на выходе прошу отписать

Comment: ошибка  HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: А вы уверены, что в его версии PHP вообще присутствуют mysql_* функции?

Comment: Какую версию php используете?

Comment: На выходе получилось: Соединение с MySQL установлено! Информация о сервере: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP php 7.0 у меня

Comment: Ну видите, значит подключиться возможно... Проверяйте скрипт который добавляет данные в базу (перед добавлением, можете проверить ещё раз подключение)